# How do i read data from this array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
[
    {
        "id":"8",
        "product_slug":"",
        "seller":"0x5144723b965a244af20ada1375b6d436441a4df4",
        "buyer":"0x659d9e424b6f1ec5dbed9a2c96822ebe79be615a",
        "message":"Hi, Smith do you want to buy my Infinix Note 4?",
        "date_created":"2020-01-12 11:24:02",
        "first_name":"Ebri",
        "last_name":"Goodness"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to research this??

Answer (score 0):

that is a JSON array and you should decode it with json_decode($data, true) in PHP.